# Windows HID Device Name Format

Tags: windows, device, hid

There are various ways to retrieve the Windows "Device Name" of a HID device, [GetRawInputDeviceInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645597(v=vs.85).aspx) with RIDI_DEVICENAME being one way to do it.

Given the example name:

\?\HID#VID_FEED&PID_DEAD#6&3559c8ea&0&0000#{378de44c-56ef-11d1-bc8c-00a0c91405dd}

I'm wondering if there is any documentation whatsoever on what is what in this string?

\?\HID#VID_AAAA&PID_BBBB#C&DDDDDD&E&FFFF#{GUID}

So the obvious ones are A(VID), B(PID) and the GUID on the end. What I'm wondering is what EXACTLY are C, D, E and F?

It seems that C and D are unique even if you plug in two of the exact same HID devices which is great for my problem, but I'd feel more comfortable if I could know exactly how this is determined on a per OS basis, or at least that it follows some known format.

I have been googling like a madman trying to figure this out, am I missing something obvious?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Re: "It seems that C and D are unique even if you plug in two of the exact same HID devices which is great for my problem..." What is the problem you're trying to solve, exactly? The exact device name format is an operating system implementation detail. You're not supposed to parse or extract information out from the device name.

Comment: I am trying to uniquely identify devices and their interfaces/outputs on a per-OS basis. You're right, I shouldn't extract information from the device name, so I won't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to a [similar MSDN post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/d68ab1dc-2615-4ae6-b3e2-b8811d0364f9/composition-of-a-device-instance-id?forum=wdk), the value represents a unique device instance ID:

> the device instance ID is unique and constant for the physical
>   location the device is plugged into, but it is also opaque and should
>   not be parsed. that means it can be used for string comparison, but
>   not for interpretation.

Comment: Very useful, thanks!! The important thing here is "that means it can be used for string comparison, but not for interpretation." That definitely answers my question.

Answer (score 2):

It is actually [device interface instance id](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-hardware/drivers/install/overview-of-device-interface-classes) (symbolic link name). And yes, its unique and persists across system restart. Some details also [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-hardware/drivers/wdf/using-device-interfaces).

You can use `CM_Get_Device_Interface_Property` or `SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceProperty` on interface instance id with `DEVPKEY_Device_InstanceId` to get device instance id (one device can have multiple interfaces).

In your example - you have a HID device. Its device id format is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-hardware/drivers/hid/hidclass-hardware-ids-for-top-level-collections).

Info on general USB devices id format is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-hardware/drivers/install/standard-usb-identifiers).

After you have device instance id you can use `CM_Get_DevNode_Property` or `SetupDiGetDeviceProperty` with `DEVPKEY_NAME` to get localized friendly name of a device (which is shown in Device Manager).

To sum up:

- `\\?\HID#VID_203A&PID_FFFC&MI_01#7&2de99099&0&0000#{378de44c-56ef-11d1-bc8c-00a0c91405dd}` - is [device interface id](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-hardware/drivers/install/overview-of-device-interface-classes) (also referred as "device interface path" or "device name" in docs). This is path in virtual device file system.
- `{378de44c-56ef-11d1-bc8c-00a0c91405dd}` - [device interface class guid](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-hardware/drivers/install/overview-of-device-interface-classes) ([GUID_DEVINTERFACE_MOUSE](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-hardware/drivers/install/guid-devinterface-mouse) in this case. It determines which IOCTLs can be called on this device. [IOCTL_MOUSE_QUERY_ATTRIBUTES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ntddmou/ni-ntddmou-ioctl_mouse_query_attributes) in this case)
- `HID\VID_203A&PID_FFFC&MI_01\7&2de99099&0&0000` - is [device instance id](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-hardware/drivers/install/device-instance-ids)

**NOTE**: exact `device interface id` format is not documented, each device interface can generate file name it want. I don't recommend you to parse it - it could be changed in later Windows version, better aquire `device instance id` - its format is documented.