# Clean way of extracting VID, PID and Serial from Device Path

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, usb

I managed to extract the device path of all connected USB devices on my computer using SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail. They usually look like the following:

```
\\?\hid#vid_0461&pid_4d15#6&219e7220&1&0000#{4d1e55b2-f16f-11cf-88cb-001111000030}
```

Given this, what's the cleanest way of extracting vid (0461), pid (4d15) and serial number (6&219e7220&1&0000)?

I thought about using IndexOf(vid_) and reading 4 characters from there (similarly for others as well), but this solution looks pretty dirty.

Or is there a known Win32 API that extracts that information nicely without having to parse that info?

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64320052/1795050

Answer (score 1):

I think I heard somewhere on StackOverflow that the device instance path is supposed to be an opaque string and parsing it is not recommended.  Instead, you should look at the device's [Hardware IDs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff546152%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Sorry this isn't a complete answer but it should get you looking in the right places.

Answer (score 1):

You can use RegularExpressions. For example to extract vid, pid and serial number:

```
string input ="\\?\hid#vid_0461&pid_4d15#6&219e7220&1&0000#{4d1e55b2-f16f-11cf-88cb-001111000030}";
Regex rx = new Regex(@"_[0-9a-fA-F]+|\{[0-9a-fA-F\-]+\}");
MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(input);

for (int i = 0; i< matches.Count; i++){
        console.writeln(matches[i].Value);
}
```